# Cannot retrieve nick from List with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to build this ASP.NET sample. Where I want add/retrieve chatroom users from `List`.

When I run this, I get no error however I don't see any nick for the connectionid given in TextBox3 either.

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add new user" OnClick="Button1_Click" Width="231px" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Fetch user by connectionid" />
```

this is the code behind:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

class User
{
    public string connectionid { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //add new user
{
    users.Add(new User { connectionid = TextBox1.Text , nick = TextBox2.Text });
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //find the nick for given connectionid
{
    foreach (User _user in users)
    {
        if (_user.connectionid == TextBox3.Text)
        {
            TextBox4.Text = _user.nick;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note about case-sensitivity, trailing spaces... and also be sure you tried adding some connectionid which will be typed correctly in the `TextBox3` before clicking the Button2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "users" list seems to get initialized on every page load so you will loose the information of the list.

Get a way to store the users list in a session (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) after button1 click so you can use it in the button2_click handler.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol - variables and objects do not persist across postbacks. Every time you click a button, the page is constructed again and `users` is reinitialised, so this will never work. You need to persist your user list somewhere. Ideally, this would be a database, but you could also use session state or cookies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Be aware that if you use session state, there are all kinds of drawbacks and pitfalls you need to consider, such as the fact that the session is reset whenever the application pool recycles and the fact that it is stored (as you'd imagine) per-session, which means that if the user uses the 'Back' button or has multiple tabs open, you stand to encounter all kinds of odd behaviour.

Comment: Not the way you're doing it, they didn't. Like I said, you need to persist it somewhere. There are any number of ways of achieving this, but a field in the codebehind is not one of them.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted given that it perfectly explained why what was occurring was occurring and presented clear alternatives.